# One hot encoding problem with p_utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to predict the class of an images corpus.

The classes of the tranining data are in a list wihch contains 4 value types : 1,2,4,5

but `p_utils.to_categorical(theList)` gives me 6 dimensions instead of 4

Could you help me to find why ?

Comment: What is most likely happening is it is assuming labels 0 and 3 can occur in the dataset as well and reserving those binary encodings if they ever occur. Use a different utility where you can specify the number of labels or convert you labels to 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply.

I have tried this (before your answer) which seems to work (around 0.997 on each epoch excepted for the first : 0.85) :

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
```

But accuracy seems to be 0 on test corpus :

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
# predict and evaluate
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
acc = np.sum(y_pred == Y_test) / np.size(y_pred)
print("Test accuracy = {}".format(acc))
```

Could you help me to find why ?

Model has good val_acc, I don't understand why accuracy test is so poor

EDIT : predict_classes returns classes like this : set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]) but I compute accuracy on this : set([1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 12, 14, 19, 20])

How tell to keras to encode correctly ?

EDIT : problem solved with this :

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y_test)
Y_test = encoder.fit_transform(Y_test) here
```

I get 99.0574712644 % accuracy

Train on 10584 samples, validate on 2646 samples
Epoch 1/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 315s 30ms/step - loss: 1.4155 - acc: 0.4357 - val_loss: 0.5511 - val_acc: 0.7827
Epoch 2/30
 5152/10584 [=============>................] - ETA: 2:16 - loss: 0.5317 - acc: 0.7999
10584/10584 [==============================] - 308s 29ms/step - loss: 0.3907 - acc: 0.8553 - val_loss: 0.1589 - val_acc: 0.9471
Epoch 3/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1351 - acc: 0.9552 - val_loss: 0.0342 - val_acc: 0.9872
Epoch 4/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 286s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0826 - acc: 0.9740 - val_loss: 0.0318 - val_acc: 0.9902
Epoch 5/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0660 - acc: 0.9797 - val_loss: 0.0354 - val_acc: 0.9875
Epoch 6/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0386 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.0244 - val_acc: 0.9913
Epoch 7/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0370 - acc: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.0171 - val_acc: 0.9943
Epoch 8/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 283s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0300 - acc: 0.9906 - val_loss: 0.0165 - val_acc: 0.9928
Epoch 9/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 283s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0355 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 0.0196 - val_acc: 0.9940
Epoch 10/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0227 - acc: 0.9930 - val_loss: 0.0162 - val_acc: 0.9958
Epoch 11/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 287s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - acc: 0.9966 - val_loss: 0.0093 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 12/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 293s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0091 - acc: 0.9976 - val_loss: 0.0098 - val_acc: 0.9962
Epoch 13/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0069 - acc: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.0113 - val_acc: 0.9962
Epoch 14/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 283s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0055 - acc: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 15/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 307s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0046 - acc: 0.9986 - val_loss: 0.0077 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 16/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 311s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0042 - acc: 0.9987 - val_loss: 0.0081 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 17/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 327s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0034 - acc: 0.9992 - val_loss: 0.0085 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 18/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 311s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0046 - acc: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0088 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 19/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 310s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0036 - acc: 0.9992 - val_loss: 0.0070 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 20/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 299s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0032 - acc: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.0082 - val_acc: 0.9970
Epoch 21/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 309s 29ms/step - loss: 0.0040 - acc: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.0083 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 22/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 298s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0037 - acc: 0.9986 - val_loss: 0.0080 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 23/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 295s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0041 - acc: 0.9987 - val_loss: 0.0082 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 24/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 291s 28ms/step - loss: 0.0026 - acc: 0.9993 - val_loss: 0.0082 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 25/30
 2240/10584 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:19 - los 2272/10584 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:19 - los 2304/10584 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:20 - loss: 0.0 2400/10584 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:21 2432/10584 [=====>........................] - ETA: 3:21 - los 2464/10584 [=====>................10584/10584 [==============================] - 291s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - acc: 0.9993 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 26/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 287s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0031 - acc: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.0077 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 27/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - acc: 0.9992 - val_loss: 0.0080 - val_acc: 0.9974
Epoch 28/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 283s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0030 - acc: 0.9986 - val_loss: 0.0078 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 29/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 284s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0027 - acc: 0.9991 - val_loss: 0.0076 - val_acc: 0.9977
Epoch 30/30
10584/10584 [==============================] - 282s 27ms/step - loss: 0.0033 - acc: 0.9988 - val_loss: 0.0074 - val_acc: 0.9974
PREDICT

Test accuracy = 0

Comment: I have printed y_pred and Y_test lists any list index matchs, how it can happen ?

Answer (score 3):

According to Keras documentation:

> **to_categorical**: Converts a class vector (integers) to the binary class
>   matrix.
>
> Arguments:
>         y: class vector to be converted into a matrix
>             (**integers from 0 to num_classes**).

The input argument to the [`to_categorical`](https://keras.io/utils/) take a list of integer that starts from zero. In your example, a list is `[1, 2, 4, 5]` which converted to 6 different classes (0 to 5):

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

If you need the same number of classes you need a transformation which available in the sklearn package named [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). It encodes labels with the value between 0 and n_classes-1. So if you pass your list, `[1, 2, 4, 5]` to LabelEncoder it converted to:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
print(le.fit_transform([1, 2, 4, 5]))
>>> [0 1 2 3]
```

As you can see, the labels start from zero which is what we needed for `to_categorical` method. The final step is to pass this list into `to_categorical` method.

```
new_labels = le.fit_transform([1, 2, 4, 5])
one_hot = to_categorical(new_labels)

>>> [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
    [0. 1. 0. 0.]
    [0. 0. 1. 0.]
    [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

**Note**: [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) also exist in sklearn packages, but it needs LabelEncoder as well in such a case.